# How to prevent memory leakage while using librosa?

Tags: audio, memory-leaks, ram, librosa

I'm trying to load a decent amount of audio segments in librosa (about 173K) all <15 sec for the most part and when I run my function, within 30 minutes my RAM is at 90%+ capacity used.. eventually crashing my computer completely.

The segments are .wav files and I've tried soundfile and audioread as standalone but same result. I also tried different iterator methods which doesn't work either. I've ran diagnostics on my RAM and everything is fine. Am I simply trying to loop through to many audio files at once? I would imagine that since my files are extremely small that this shouldn't be a problem. I've had no issues with memory leakage in the past or running large model job batches.

RAM: 16.0 GB
Disk space for cache: 2TB of space

**Tried this:**

```
def load_wavs(wav_dir, sr):

    wavs = list()
    for file in os.listdir(wav_dir):
        file_path = os.path.join(wav_dir, file)
        wav, _ = librosa.load(file_path, sr = sr, mono = True)
        #wav = wav.astype(np.float64)
        wavs.append(wav)

    return wavs
```

**Tried this:**

```
def load_segs(audio_arrays):

    segments_data = []
    for a in audio_arrays:
        data = librosa.load(a, sr=16000, mono=True)
        segments_data.append(data)
        print(librosa.display.waveplot(data))
```

**And tried this:**

```
audio_data_all = []

for i in audio_arrays: 
    data = librosa.load(i, sr=16000, mono=True)   
    audio_data_all.append(data)
```

**And this in each function:**

```
audio_data = [librosa.load(i, sr=16000, mono=True) for i in audio_arrays]
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How much RAM does the process use?

Comment: The process uses all of it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each loaded audio file will take up memory. This is roughly `samplewidth_bytes * channels * samplerate * seconds_per_sample * number_of_samples` bytes.
Using 16 kHz samplerate, loaded to 64 bit float, 1 channel, up to 15 seconds, and 173k audio files this is: `(8*1*16000*15*173000)/1e9` = 332 GB.
So it will not fit in 16 GB of RAM.

This is not a memory leak issue, just that you are trying to load too much data at a time. Process the audio files one by one or in batches of up to 1-2k files instead.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. It does work fine with 1500 files at once. Only problem now is that I have 118 separate batches. Is there any way to automate the batch processing without running each function on each folder containing the audio files 118 times? This is my first time using librosa at this large of a scale. I'd have to implement some sort of delay right?